# does codenameone support android biometrics

Tags: codenameone

Does codenameone have support for

- androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt
- android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt

I tried to use these classes in codeoneproject in native but i got the following errors from build server:
*error: package android.hardware.biometrics does not exist*
*error: package androidx.biometric does not exist*

Do you have any plans on supporting BiometricPrompt?

Comment: In addition to Diamonds answer you can see how the source of the extension got that native code working by including the right google play flags.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an existing Codename One extension called **FingerprintScanner**.

Search for that in Codename One Extension Store and download it to your project.

Use it as follows:

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint("Prompt message: Approve this process using biometric.", value -> {
    Log.p("Biometric scan is successfull!");
}, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
    Log.p("Biometric scan failed!");
});
```

Comment: I know that there is codenameone FingerprintScanner extension but it uses android **FingerprintMenager** class which is deprecated in API level 28.  **BiometricPrompt**  is used instead.